# "allow the origin of the assets in your Rails config file" ? (Heroku to Railway - no styling, images not loading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

along with many others it would seem, I have attempted to shift my hobby apps from Heroku to Railway. I haven’t had tremendous success as both of the apps I’ve transferred (which work fine locally and on Heroku) experience the same problem on Railway – no styling and images not loading.

I raised the issue on the Railway community help system and a member of the team replied
“My guess here is that you need to allow the origin of the assets in your Rails config file”. I asked if he could expand on this, but didn’t get a reply.

Can anyone provide a further clue. Is there a particular line of code I should add to the config/environments/production.rb file?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: For those who want to track this topic further, this appears to be a corresponding GitHub ticket: https://github.com/railwayapp/nixpacks/issues/546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed (with guesswork) to (at least temporarily) solve this. I changed the ‘builder’ on the Railway dashboard from the default Railway setting ‘Nixpacks’ to ‘Heroku Buildpacks’ (which is said to be deprecated). Images and styling now as expected. Noone from the Railway team has indicated they are investigating the issue or trying to fix it...